# Does every holomorphic function $f$ defined on an open set $U$ have a primitive?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have read that a holomorphic function in an open disc has a primitive in that disc. Does this mean that for any holomorphic function $f$ in any open set $U,$ that $f$ has a primitive? I say this because I can take a large enough open disc to cover the open set $U$ and find its primitive there. Is this a correct way of thinking?

Comment: Locally, if $f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\ldots$, try $F(z)=a_0z+\frac{a_1}2z^2+\frac{a_2}3z^3+\ldots$

Comment: I understand...but does my reasoning above make sense?

Comment: Oh, I overread that. - No, that makes no sense. After all, you cannot ensure that $f$ is holomorphic in the larger disk. For example, $f(z)=\frac1{z-1}$ is holomorphic in the open set $U=\{\,z=x+iy\in\Bbb C: |x|<1,|y|< 1\,\}$ but not holomorhic in the smallest (or any other) open disk containing $U$, $D=\{\,z\in\Bbb C:|z|<\sqrt 2\,\}$, because necessarily $1\in D$. -- Or try $f(z)=\frac1z$ with $U=\{\,z\in\Bbb C:0<|z|<1\,\}$ and face the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not true.

Consider the function $f(z)=1/z$, which is holomorphic in the open set $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, but has no antiderivative.

The key fact is that an open disc is simply connected, but the union of open discs may not be.

The statement is true for *simply connected* open sets, so it's true that you can find an antiderivative over an open disc around each point, but these may not “glue together”.

On a non simply connected open set there may exist functions not admitting an antiderivative.

Your idea cannot work: consider the situation above: there is no “large enough disc” that covers the given open set. Even if you consider $1/z$ over $D\setminus\{0\}$, where $D$ is the open disc at the origin with radius $1$, you incur in the same problem: whatever point $z_0$ you take in $D\setminus\{0\}$ you have a suitable disc around $z_0$ over which $f(z)=1/z$ has an antiderivative, but this disc can have radius at most $|z_0|$, because it cannot contain $0$.

What you could do is “glueing together” the local antiderivatives, but this doesn't work either. But it's the idea around [*analytic continuation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: That applies to the *claim*, but not not to the *proof idea* the OP has in mind. E.g., the first example in my comment above has a simply connected $U$ and $f$ has an antiderivative there - but the OP's idea of enlarging $U$ to a disk region in order to find it is doomed.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Added some comments and a link.